# One to one Association in Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm kind of new in Rails and couldn't make my Models relationship to work, and I don't know the reason. I've tried in many ways and followed many different tutorials, but couldn't figure out the right way. Do you know what's wrong with my code? How can I test it?

I have two models, with has_one association User and Profile. Profile belongs to User. So every time I add a user, I would also add a Profile.

This is the migration file for User model

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is migration file for Profile model

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change

    drop_table :profiles
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :lastname
      t.string :phone
      t.string :address
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :country
      t.string :gender, :limit => 10
      t.string :zipcode
      t.references :users, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

model Profile

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

model User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_one :profile
end
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: what have you tried and what errors are you getting ? The question doesn't convey much info to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the migration.

`Profile` belongs to `User`, so in the `create_profiles` migration you should have:

`t.references :user, foreign_key: true`

(`user` instead of `users`).

With your code, the `Profile` model will have `users_id` field when it should have `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the observation. That was exactly the problem.